# Cannot modify apps on Facebook

Tags: facebook-apps

I create this topic because when I try to modify my facebook apps, I constantly get the following error :

> Oops Something went wrong. We're working on getting this fixed as soon as we can. You may be able to try again.

I tried in Firefox and Internet Explorer to check if the problem was coming from my web-browser, and then I checked from a friends station, but I still get this error.

Just wanted to know if someone else had this problem ? Maybe I have to do something from my side ? Or can I just wait for Facebook team to solve this ?

Thank you in advance.

Bahan

Comment: no idea what's causing it, but I'm seeing the same thing for my facebook app.  I'm trying to enable embedded browser OAuth login but as soon as I click 'save changes' to commit the changes I receive the 'oops something went wrong. we're working on getting it fixed as soon as we can' popup.  Not very helpful

Comment: looks like this bug has been reported: https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/1390676977854782/